# Disposable Ajax.ActionLink like Ajax.BeginForm

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I can write form and it's content like this:

```
@using(Ajax.BeginForm(...)){
    // html content here
}
```

Rendered as:

```
<form>
    // html content here
</form>
```

Is it possible to do same with Ajax.ActionLink?

```
@using(Ajax.ActionLink(...)){
    // html content here
}
```

Rendered:

```
<a>
    // html content here
</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't, Ajax.ActionLink returns [MvcHtmlString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.mvchtmlstring%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) which is not disposable.

You can instead create the link yourself as in this [extension method example](http://forums.asp.net/p/1702210/4518688.aspx/1?Re%20Quick%20question%20about%20Ajax%20ActionLink%20and%20span).